# ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a simple print function but I am getting a strange error. This is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.2
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(1,10,1)
print(a)
for i in a:
    print(i)
    print(type(i))
    print("{0:<12g}".format(i))
```

The output is:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
1
<class 'numpy.int64'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("{0:<12g}".format(i))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'
```

Why does print take the "numpy.int64" as a string? I have to add that it works perfectly for a normal list: (e.g. [1,2,3,4]) I would be most grateful to any ideas on this issue, thanks ;-).

Comment: You're not actually using Python 3.2, are you? There isn't a finished version of numpy for Python 3. Also, I cannot reproduce using Python 2.7 and Python 32-bit on Windows (where they're `int32`s not `int64`s). This could be specific to a certain version of numpy or Python, or specific to 64-bit Python.

Comment: I am using Python 3.2.2, atleast this is what Python says above its copyright notice when I type python3 in the command line! (I am using Linux)

Comment: Add `import sys; print(sys.version)` to your code to see what version this script is actually being run with.

Comment: I think I found the solution: "g" in the print formatting only works for floats. It doesn't work for Integers. So when I change the array definition to:

a=np.arange(0,10,1, dtype="f8")

It works! The error should have said:

Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'int'. Unfortunately I don't have enough "Reputation" to answer my own question!

Comment: The command "import sys" and "print(sys.version)" gives: 3.2.2 (default, Mar 29 2012, 10:43:55) and [GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1675) and should be fixed in version 2.0. In the interim, you can use the old syntax `%f` that works.

Comment: I think I found the solution: "g" in the print formatting only works for floats. It doesn't work for Integers. So when I change the array definition to: a=np.arange(0,10,1, dtype="f8") It works! The error should have said: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'int'. Unfortunately I don't have enough "Reputation" to answer my own question!

Comment: @astroboy That's not quite right, as with `int32` I don't get an error with numpy 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Someone will be able to give you a more in-depth answer, but what I think is happening here is that you're using `"{0:<12g}".format(i)` which uses special formatting. If you'd try `"\{{0}:<12g\}".format(i)` you'd probably get better results. Using the slashes there escapes the `{}`'s which is what is giving you the error.

Comment: With this change the error changes to: ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string