# Error in string.format using scientific notation with dtype=float32

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this work

```py
print "{:e}".format(array([1e-10],dtype="float64")[0])
1.000000e-10
```

but not this?

```py
print "{:e}".format(array([1e-10],dtype="float32")[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9a0800b4df65> in <module>()
----> 1 print "{:e}".format(array([1e-10],dtype="float32")[0])

ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str
```

**Update:**
I tried with numpy version 1.6.1 and Python 2.7.3.

```
me@serv8:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
me@serv8:~$ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__"
1.6.1
me@serv8:~$ python -c "from numpy import array; print \"{:e}\".format(array([1e-10],dtype=\"float32\")[0])"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: What version of numpy are you using since on 1.7.1 both work?

Comment: Both work on *numpy 1.6.2*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Numpy Bug #1675

This is a bug which was fixed in Numpy 1.6.2 [(Change log here)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/).

### Analysis

Hmm... it looks like we can get the types okay:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a64 = array([1e-10],dtype="float64")[0]
>>> a32 = array([1e-10],dtype="float32")[0]
>>> type(a32)
<type 'numpy.float32'>
>>> type(a64)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

So, let's try printing now:

```
>>> print a32
1e-10
>>> print a64
1e-10
```

Okay, that seems to work. Let's try printing with exponent notation:

```
>>> print('{0:e}'.format(a64))
1.000000e-10
>>> print('{0:e}'.format(a32))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'
```

Doing some googling, I found a similar reference to the bug #1675 which is supposedly fixed in Numpy version 1.6.2. [(Change log here)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/)

Based on this, I subsequently installed 1.6.2 and tried what you tried above. It works.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> print "{:e}".format(array([1e-10],dtype="float64")[0])
1.000000e-10
>>> print "{:e}".format(array([1e-10],dtype="float32")[0])
1.000000e-10
```

Comment: Thanks. But with which google search terms did you find the bug report?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277168/651848) using the search string "python Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'". However, it contains a dead link to projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1675. So, I then did a search for "numpy bug 1675" which then helped me find the change log on sourceforge.net.

Comment: Damn, I knew it. I could have found it myself. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry about it -- it happens :-)